# MySQL calculated column using two tables

Tags: mysql

I've got a table of clubMembers with an integer id (PK)

I've got another table which just lists a couple of ids (life members of the club)

I want to create a view with all the clubMembers, plus an extra column that calculates their membership type which works something like this:

```
if (clubMember.id is in lifeMembers) result = "Life"
elseif (clubMember.dateJoinedClub is over 1 year ago) result = "Full"
else result = "Probationary"
```

But I have no idea how to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE`, like this:

```
SELECT cm.*,
  CASE WHEN lm.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Life'
       WHEN now() > DATE_ADD(cm.dateJoinedClub, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN 'Full'
       ELSE 'Probationary'
  END AS `result`
FROM clubMembers cm
LEFT JOIN lifeMembers lm
ON cm.id = lm.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` on `lifeMembers`, then something like this to get the `result` using [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
IF(lifeMembers.id IS NOT NULL, "Life", IF(clubMember.dateJoinedClub < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, "Full", "Probationary")) AS res
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'case' as definition of your extra column in view:

```
case when (clubMember.id in (select clubMemberId from lifeMembers)) then 'Life'
when (clubMember.dateJoinedClub < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) then 'Full'
else 'Probationary' end as ExtraColumn
```